# Creating Context from Model Python Variables

Tags: python-3.x, pyomo

I'm using

```
pyomo                     5.6.6                    py36_0    conda-forge
```

It seems that an `AbstractModel` Python variable can't be used to create a context. For example:

```
my_model = AbstractModel(name="Test")
# Create sets, parameters, variables
# ...
with my_model as m:
    # ...
```

Gives an error:

```
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Wondering if I'm missing something, or if that's not currently possible at all. I was hoping to make my code cleaner with a context.

Comment: No, Pyomo does not support what you're trying to do with a context but I'm not sure I understand your motivation for wanting to use Pyomo models in a context or how it would make your code cleaner. Are you just trying to temporarily rename the Python variable for your model?

Comment: It was just to avoid repeating `my_model` several times in a block of code. Not a real problem, though.

Comment: You can do something like `m = my_model` and then use `m` in the rest of your script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `with`, Python evaluates this expression, calls the **__enter__** method on the resulting value (which is called a “context guard”), and assigns whatever **__enter__** returns to the variable given by as. Python will then execute the code body, and no matter what happens in that code, call the guard object’s **__exit__** method

So it's better to create a new class that inherits the **AbstractModel** and in that, you can define the **enter** and **exit** methods.

eg:

```
class NewAbstractModel(AbstractModel): 
   def __enter__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
       # do_something 
   def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
       # do_something

newmodel = NewAbstractModel(name="test")
with newmodel as m:
   # do_something with m
```

For reference use this [Understanding Python's "with" statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)

Comment: Thanks, but my question was if Pyomo implements support for the `with` statement in its models.

Comment: Nope they don't if you need to then you can use this which is up to you.